# How to get all contacts and write into file for Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

The problem I want to solve:
Get all the contacts info like name and Mobile phone and write it into file and save in ISO.

1. How to use SearchAsync if I want to search available contacts in the phone?
2. How to iterate the return-results and write to file one by one of the contact into a file?

Here's the code I have:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Contacts contacts = new Contacts();     
    contacts.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(contacts_SearchCompleted);   
    contacts.SearchAsync(displayName,FilterKind.DisplayName,null);    
    //search for all contacts   
    contacts.SearchAsync(string.Empty, FilterKind.None, null);
}
```

**Update:**

1. The below code throw NullException error if the PhoneNumber is Empty. Why?
2. How to get all the possibile phone number other than `result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().ToString();`
3. Same question for EmailAddresses

Using this to search all contacts in the phone:

```
contacts.SearchAsync(searchterm, FilterKind.None, null);

void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    int intTTL = e.Results.Count();
    if (intTTL != 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(intTTL.ToString());
        foreach (var result in e.Results)
        {
            string strTTL;
            string strName = result.DisplayName;
            string MobileNo = result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            strTTL = strName + "," + MobileNo;
            MessageBox.Show(strTTL);
        }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have not entered any contact info at all.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read the MSDN section on developing WP7 applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this article to see how to get the Contacts](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/08/31-days-of-mango-day-8-contacts-api/):

To iterate:

```
void contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(var contact in e.Results)
    {
        // write to Isolated storage
    }
}
```

See [this MSDN page for writing files in isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Assume name and phone Number are entered. But What if email address and other are not entered? The search complete will throw an error of null exception. Ie  txtBlkCtc.text = contact.Email . In this case, what to do to continue iterating?

Comment: Then first check the values you are interested in and skip those fields that are empty. I doubt ` txtBlkCtc.text = contact.Email` will not generate an exception when the Email property is null or empty. It will only generate an exception when contact is null.

Comment: I downloaded the app and tried to get all the default Contacts on the emulator. There were 7 contact, but it throw error on 4th contact as there is null in PhoneNumber. Hope u can help on the Questions. Thanks

Comment: You should test the PhoneNumber for null before using it.

Comment: problem solved. use Foreach to iterate phonenumbers collections. There should be ok even the 2nd or 3rd phone number is null. Thanks